# How to indicate in Drive-sdk that my application can open files with the mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk'?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, shortcut

I'm working on google app engine with python and Drive-sdk.
My application creates shortcuts (files with no content and the mimeType 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk')

when I try to specify in Drive-sdk that the default mimeType my app can open is : 'application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk' i get the following message:

''MIME types beginning with "application/vnd.google-apps." are reserved for internal use. If you want your app to open Google documents, use the import option below. ''

ps: the import option allows users to open files that can be converted to a format that this app can open

Answer (score 1):

To handle shortcuts you application creates in Drive, you don't need to do anything other than create the shortcut. As noted on the 'Setting MIME types and extensions' section of the [Enable the Drive Platform](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/enable-sdk) documentation, you should leave the default MIME type blank

> **Note:** If you only need to let Google Drive users open shortcuts to files not actually stored in Drive, you can leave the MIME types blank.

When a user clicks on a shortcut file, Drive will redirect the user to the site you registered via the Open URL section and handling it on your side will be exactly the same as described in [Open Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open).